# MySQL / doctrine issue with a left join

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have an issue with a doctrine query to the database and I'm not sure what is wrong.
here's the deal:
this is the actual mysql query I used to create the database:

```
            create table productos ( 
                codigoProducto int (8) unsigned auto_increment primary key, 
                nombre varchar(100) not null,
                id_categoria smallint(3) unsigned,
                descripcion text,
                foto varchar(100),
                precio smallint (4) unsigned not null, 
                visitado int (7),
                habilitado boolean,

                foreign key (id_categoria) 
                references  categorias(id)
                on update cascade
                on delete restrict
            )engine=innoDB;

            create table facturas( 
                id int (8) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
                id_comprador int (7) unsigned, 
                metodo_pago boolean,
                forma_entrega boolean,
                fecha datetime,

                foreign key (id_comprador)
                references  compradores(id)
                on update cascade
                on delete cascade
            )engine=innoDB;

            create table detallefactura(
                id int(8) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
                id_producto int(8) unsigned,
                id_factura int(8) unsigned,
                cantidad smallint (4),

                foreign key(id_producto)
                references productos(codigoProducto)
                on update cascade
                on delete cascade,

                foreign key(id_factura)
                references facturas(id)
                on update cascade
                on delete cascade
            )engine=innoDB;
```

"detalleFactura" is the join table for 'productos' and 'facturas', in order to have more than 1 product per invoice. So with the following I'm trying to take all products bought in one invoice:

```
            static function traerProductosComprados($id){
                $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('d.id, p.nombre, p.precio, d.cantidad')
                        ->from('Detallefactura d')
                        ->leftjoin('d.Productos p')
                        ->where('d.id_factura = ?',$id);
                return $query->execute()->toArray();
            }
```

if I make an echo of the query, it shows the following:

```
            SELECT d.id, p.nombre, p.precio, d.cantidad FROM Detallefactura d LEFT JOIN d.Productos p WHERE d.id_factura = ?
```

when I paste this to the phpmyadmin, it throws the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE d.id_factura = ?    LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1;

I'm out of ideas now, please tell me if there's something else I'm missing!

Comment: Doctrine show you an error? How do you *echo* the query?

Comment: That query that you echoed is a DQL statement. It won't work in PhpMyAdmin, which only speaks SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `ON` clause for your left join

Comment: Please don't answer when you don't know. The syntax to perfom a left join in Doctrine is right. [See the doc](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#join-syntax)

Comment: The problem is maybe he has no reference from table class Productos to Detallefactura so Docrtine generates wrong query. You can owerride ON clause manually in DQL

Comment: Instead of override the ON clause, I think it's better to fix the jointure.

Comment: You know, you can post your own answer to point better way to fix it :)

Comment: I asked few questions because I don't have an answer yet :)